# Find first element in tuple based on parameterized primitive

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, c++20

I have a contrived example of what I would like to achieve.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <array>

template <int Val>    
struct Value
{
    static constexpr auto aValue = Val;

    double arbitrary_operation() { return aValue * 2.0; };
};

struct Meta
{
    auto do_calculation(std::floating_point auto x) { return x * 4.0; }
};

constexpr auto Values = std::tuple{Value<5>{}, Value<6>{}, Value<7>{}};
constexpr auto ValueMetadata = std::array<std::pair<int, Meta>, 3>{{{5, Meta{}}, {6, Meta{}}, {7, Meta{}}}};

void do_work()
{
    std::array<double, ValueMetadata.size()> results;
    for (auto& m : ValueMetadata)
    {
        // find first element in Values tuple that corresponds to parameterized integer (m.first == aValue)
        auto value = get_first_element_in_values_tuple<m.first>(); // TODO
        // perform arbitrary_operation on that Value and aggregate results
        auto arbitrary_value = value.arbitrary_operation();
        auto result = m.second.do_calculation(arbitrary_value);
        // store in results array
    }
}
```

The body of `do_work` is presenting some difficult - and I'm wondering where this can be performed at compile-time.

Comment: in reality does `arbitrary_operation` produce a result? Are you aggregating those results?

Comment: That's right - in reality, `arbitrary_operation` will return a finite numerical value, of which all those values are aggregated. Edited code example.

Comment: Are all the values in `Values` a `Value`? If so, is there any reason you need it to be a tuple? Making it an array makes more sense in that case. Also related/dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55775399

Comment: Yes @cigien, all the values in `Values` are of type `Value`.

I came across that related item previously but wasn't sure if there was a more idiomatic `c++20` approach that is possibly more readable and/or resolved at compile time.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's something new in C++20 that makes this more readable, but there may be. You should definitely be able to do this at compile time though. Also, if you make `Values` a `std::array`, you can even use constexpr algorithms.

Comment: Problem being is that the `Value` type is a template - hence why I can't use a `std::array` (otherwise that would have been my first choice).

Comment: What is the `Meta` class for?

Comment: Updated example @康桓瑋

Comment: @cigien `Values<5>` and `Values<6>` are two different types, you can't put them into the same array.

Comment: @RyanHaining Oops, you're absolutely right. That was careless of me.

Answer (score 1):

So I'm not sure what the templated `Value` class brings you. Why not make them non-template, then you can just make `Values` an `std::array`, and use `constexpr` algorithms from C++20?

---

Either way, if you insist on the `tuple` solution, here's one way you can create a `tuple_find_if` function with the help of C++20 `constexpr` algorithms and [`std::index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence):

```cpp
template<typename Tuple, typename Func, std::size_t ... N>
consteval auto tuple_find_if_impl(Tuple tup, Func func, std::index_sequence<N...>)
{
    constexpr auto compares = std::array{func(std::get<N>(tup))...};
    constexpr auto index = std::ranges::find(compares, true) - compares.begin();
    return std::get<index>(tup);
}


template<typename ... Ts, typename Func>
consteval auto tuple_find_if(std::tuple<Ts...> tup, Func func)
{
    return tuple_find_if_impl(tup, func, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>{});
}
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/cEfPoPbdc

---

And here's a recursive version that works with C++17:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename ... Ts, typename Func, std::size_t ... N>
constexpr auto tuple_find_if_impl(std::tuple<T, Ts...> tup, Func func, std::index_sequence<N...>)
{
    if constexpr(func(std::get<0>(tup)))
    {
        return std::get<0>(tup);
    }
    else
    {
        return tuple_find_if_impl(std::make_tuple(std::get<N + 1>(tup)...), func, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts) - 1>{});
    }
}

template<typename ... Ts, typename Func>
constexpr auto tuple_find_if(std::tuple<Ts...> tup, Func func)
{
    return tuple_find_if_impl(tup, func, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts) - 1>{});
}
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/sc5Txronh

Answer (score 1):

You can first convert the `tuple` to an `array` and use `std::find` to find the appropriate index, then use `variant` to type-erasure the index.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <variant>

template<std::size_t N>
constexpr auto VarIndexArray = []<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
  using VarType = std::variant<std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>...>;
  return std::array{VarType{std::in_place_index<Is>}...};
}(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});

void do_work() {
  std::array<double, ValueMetadata.size()> results;
  constexpr auto ValueArray = std::apply(
    [](auto... vals) { return std::array{decltype(vals)::aValue...}; }, Values);
  constexpr auto IndexArray = VarIndexArray<std::tuple_size_v<decltype(Values)>>;

  for (auto& m : ValueMetadata) {
    // find first element in Values tuple that corresponds to parameterized integer
    auto index = std::ranges::find(ValueArray, m.first) - ValueArray.begin();
    auto result = std::visit(
      [&m](auto index) {
        auto arbitrary_value = std::get<index>(Values).arbitrary_operation();
        auto result = m.second.do_calculation(arbitrary_value); 
        return result;
      }, IndexArray[index]);
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/374K6Pf8d)

Answer (score 1):

I may be misinterpreting your constraints, but if I understand correctly, you want to find the matching tuple element for each pair in your array, then aggregate the results. Depending on exactly what you want there's certainly better solutions using fold expressions and index sequences, but I believe I have something that works and produces a compile time result:

[live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qzissVLwTJ9Zbld9)

```
template <int I, std::size_t TupleIndex>
consteval double find_match() {
  // Compare I to the current aValue, if they match, return the val.
  if constexpr (I == std::get<TupleIndex>(Values).aValue) {
    return std::get<TupleIndex>(Values).val();
  } else {
    // Otherwise, move onto the next element of the tuple.
    return find_match<I, TupleIndex+1>();
  }
}

template <std::size_t I>
consteval double accumulate_matches() {
  if constexpr (I == ValueMetadata.size()) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    // Change this expression to accumulate with something
    // other than a simple summation.
    
    // 0 to start searching at the beginning of the tuple.
    // +1 in the recursive call to get to the next element of ValueMetadata
    return find_match<ValueMetadata[I].first, 0>()
        + accumulate_matches<I+1>();
  }
}

consteval double get_total() {
  return accumulate_matches<0>();
}
```